# Internalized ViewController switching in Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, timer, viewcontroller

As a note: This is my first community post, so excuse me for any possible mistakes

Anyways, here is my question:
I’m working on an iOS Application and I want to switch between two ViewControllers (They are in a Single storyboard and are using the same class) automatically and after a specific amount of time (e.g 1 second). I think I should use a Timer to do this, but I might be wrong...
Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks
Mr. Swift

Comment: Can you try to write something yourself first, and if that didn't work, show the code here so we can tell you where the problem is?

Comment: Come again?  How do you go from switching view controllers to using the Timer?  You should not use the Timer unless you are literally going to run a clock.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting exactly but If you want to change views with tabs or swipe, you should either use UITabViewController or UICollectionView.

You can take reference from WhatsApp upper bar(changes View with Swipe), which can be made using UICollectionView or Youtube lower tabbar, which is done by UiTabViewController

Comment: "Youtube lower tabbar, which is done by UiTabViewController"  Says who!?  Do you work for YouTube?  I am certain they use a subclass of `UIViewController`.

Comment: Thanks, but I want the two View Controllers To switch without user interaction

Comment: Like introduction screen or slideshow? If it's introduction screen like in use UIPageViewController and slideshow can be easily done by UICollectionView